# Binding not working correctly in silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, binding

I am using a DataGrid in my Silverlight project which contains a custom checkbox column.  I have bound its `Command` property to a property of my ViewModel class.  Now, the problem is that I want to send the "selected item" of DataGrid through the command parameter for which I have written the following code :

```xml
<sdk:DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Margin="10,0,10,0" Name="dataGridOrders" ItemsSource="{Binding OrderList}" Height="190">
    <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
        <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Select">
            <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <CheckBox>
                        <is:Interaction.Triggers>
                            <is:EventTrigger EventName="Checked">
                                <is:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Source={StaticResource ExecutionTraderHomePageVM},Path=OrderSelectedCommand,Mode=TwoWay}"
                                                        CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=dataGridOrders,Path=SelectedItem}" />
                            </is:EventTrigger>
                            <is:EventTrigger EventName="Unchecked">
                                <is:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Source={StaticResource ExecutionTraderHomePageVM},Path=OrderSelectedCommand,Mode=TwoWay}"
                                                        CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=dataGridOrders,Path=SelectedItem}" />
                            </is:EventTrigger>
                        </is:Interaction.Triggers>
                    </CheckBox>
```

But I am always getting `null` in the parameter of my command's `Execute` method. I have tried with other properties of DataGrid such as `Width`, `ActualHeight` etc. but of no use. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is one of name-scoping.  In short, the XAML inside a `DataTemplate` has its own 'namescope' and can't see any names outside of it.  In particular, it won't be able to find the parent `DataGrid` as that lies outside the `DataTemplate`.

I'm not sure why you're listening out to checked and unchecked events and firing commands based on them.  It's not entirely clear what you're trying to achieve.  Instead, I would use a two-way binding to bind the `IsChecked` property of the `CheckBox` to a `bool` property in your (row-level) view-model class, and call the command functionality from this `bool` property's setter.  You can get hold of the selected item by binding a view-model property to the `DataGrid`s `SelectedItem` property with a two-way binding.

Comment: Let me explain what I want to achieve :I have got a List<Orders> object in my ViewModel class. When the checkbox is clicked, I am adding the corresponding row in List<Orders> (through DataGrid SelectedItem).Similarly when a row is unchecked, that row is removed from the list.The solution you provided is working fine. Infact I myself thought of this approach before. The reason why I didn't use it was that I thought : Since the checkbox are bound to a single property, checking one of them would result in checking of all the checkboxes automatically. But this isn't happening. Can you explain why?

Comment: @HarshMaurya: Why would the checkboxes be bound to a single property?  Surely they would be bound to the same property on different instances of your `Order` view-model class?

Answer (score 0):

i think you should used EventTrigger like

```
<is:EventTrigger EventName="Checked">
<is:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=DataContext.CheckBoxUncheckedCommand}"  CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
                                </is:EventTrigger>
```